# CSS, Font face in chrome and others browsers

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts, mozilla

I have specific problem. I use Open sans from google fonts, and in Chrome this look fine, but in other browsers this not look ok. I need, this should work like chrome. Can you have solution for this problem?

My css font import:

```
@import url(fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic&subset=latin,latin-ext);
```

And screen:
Chrome (I want in all browser the same effect):

[image]

Other browsers:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Your URL needs a protocol.

Comment: Yes, I know, i'm new user and i can't add more than 2 links in post

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the protocol `http://` to `https://` will make the URL known as "secure" in other browsers.

If you test it with `http://` in IE you may notice the notification:

> Only secure content is displayed.

So that is preventing the Google font to be loaded, unless it's securely loaded with `https://`, same as Firefox.

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/f86dt8uo/1/):

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic&subset=latin,latin-ext);

p {font-family:"Open Sans";font-size:24px;}
```

```html
<p>Open Sans</p>
```

Comment: This no work, in different browsers (chrome, mozilla) effect is the same like on my screen.

Comment: Use the JSFiddle link I posted to test it on each browser. In my test it works in Chrome, Firefox, Safari and IE.

Comment: I see that you are referring to font rendering issue in Win 7. See my test on Win 8 http://i.imgur.com/qbSD839.jpg. Try using standard call for @font-face using CSS with [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com), that may work for Win 7 better than Google font.

Comment: Open Sans Condensed is for all browser like normal Open Sans, thanks